# How to solve my error in this shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, sh, heredoc

I have been trying to run the following command but it gives me the following error but when I type command in terminal it runs, how to fix this

Command:

```
host=''
user=''
pass=''
path='path'
srcfile='file.txt'
lftp -u $user,$pass $host   << --EOF--
set ssl:verify-certificate no
put $srcfile
quit
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Your here-document isn't terminated: add a `--EOF--` at the end of your `lftp` commands

Comment: where exactly? I have put --EOF-- at that line

Comment: after the `quit`, add a line containing exactly `--EOF--`

Answer (score 2):

If you told shell that you're using here document you have to tell it
where it ends:

```
lftp -u $user,$pass $host   << --EOF--
set ssl:verify-certificate no
put $srcfile
quit
--EOF--
```